# How to disable a button inside a rectangle control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable a button that is inside a rectangle control. I have tried the following code to disable this :

```
btn.Enabled=false;
```

But it does not works for me as I am new to Windows programming.

Comment: it's a bool value not a string

Comment: Can you post the function or module that you have this command in?

Comment: can you update the code with rectangle added with button ?

Comment: R u there ? why doesn't update the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 btn.Enabled = false;
```